# How to pass values to an inner array when creating Angular object?

Tags: angular, typescript

Below are the `Conversation` & `Message` models I am using in my Ionic 5 / Angular app:

```
export class Conversation {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public userId: string,
        public mechanicId: string,
        public messages: Message[]
    ) { }
}
```

And here is the Message model:

```
export class Message {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public text: string,
        public userId: string,
        public timestamp: string
    ) { }
}
```

When a user creates a `Conversation` object, I want them to add 1 `Message` object within the `Conversation`.

Then when other uses are *updating* the `Conversation` *(i.e. sending more messages)*, they will just be pushing another `Message` to the `Conversation`.

Here is what I have so far for creating a `Conversation`:

```
onSendMessage() {
    this.conversationService.addConversation(
        this.mechanicToContact.id,
        this.form.value.message
    );
}
```

I've tried the following method in my `ConversationService`:

```
addConversation(mechanicId: string, message: string) {
    const newConversation = new Conversation(
      Math.random().toString(),
      this.authService.userId,
      mechanicId,
      new Message(Math.random().toString(), message, this.authService.userId, mechanicId)
      );
  }
```

But I'm getting this error when trying to create the new Message:

Argument of type 'Message' is not assignable to type parameter of 'Message[]'

I'm not sure how I should pass the remaining attributes of the `Message`. Can someone please tell me how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the class `Conversation` expects a `Message[]`, which is an array of messages, and you are sending a `Message`. Couple ways to fix this. One being:

```
const newConversation = new Conversation(conversationId, userId, mechanicId, [ message ]);
```

This just wraps the message in an array.

---

Another one:

```
export class Conversation {
    public messages: Message[];

    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public userId: string,
        public mechanicId: string,
        messages: Message | Message[]
    ) { 
      this.messages = Array.isArray(messages) ? messages : [ messages ];
    }

    addMessages(messages: Message | Message[]): void {
       this.messages.push(
          ...(Array.isArray(messages) ? messages : [ messages ])
       );
    }
}
```

This will be able to accept both an array as a message object, and handles the correct way inside the class.

---

It's more common to have a service handle this. You can think of something like this:

```
export interface Conversation {
  id: string;
  userId: string;
  mechanicId: string;
  messages: Message[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConversationService {
  private conversations: Conversation[];

  addConversation(mechanicId: string, message: string): Conversation {
    const conversation: Conversation = {
      id: getUniqueUid() // something like this,
      userId: this.userService.getUserId() // something like this
      mechanicId,
      messages: [ this.createMessage(message) ] 
    };

    this.conversations.push(conversation);

    return conversation;
  }

  addToConversation(id: string, mechanicId: string, message: string): Conversation {
    const conversation = this.getConversation(id);

    if (conversation) {
      conversation.messages.push(
        this.createMessage(message)
      );
    }

    return conversation;
  }

  private createMessage(message: string): Message {
    return {
      id: getUniqueMid() // something like this,
      text: message,
      userId: this.userService.getUserId(),
      timestamp: Date.now()
    };
  }

  private getConversation(id: string): Conversation | undefined {
    return this.conversations.find((conversation) => conversation.id === id); 
  }
}
```

Comment: A quick question: why declare type `messages: Message | Message[]` when it'll always be assigned an array of `Message`? Wouldn't `messages: Message[]` suffice?

Comment: @MichaelD the constructor is how you call it with `new`, if you declare it like this, you can call it with `Message` and `Message[]`. However the public class property `messages` is of type `Message[]`. You can see that declared above the constructor. The constructor parameter `messages` is not the same as `this.messages` of the class

Comment: When creating the Conversation initially, I will only be passing one message.

Also, when updating the Conversation (i.e. sending a message back), I will still only be passing one message.

Does your solution provide for this?

Comment: @user9847788 this solution provides for allowing a single message object as constructor parameter of your `Conversation` class. The updating of a conversation should probably use a `push` on the `this.messages()`, but you did not show that piece of code

Comment: @PierreDuc I've updated my question to show more of my code & explain my problem

Comment: @user9847788 Right, my solution would work for this, either one of them.

Comment: @PierreDuc OK, great. But how should I pass the other `Message` attributes? So that they're added to the `Conversation` object?

Comment: @user9847788 I've added a `addMessages` method

Comment: @user9847788 Be aware though, that it's not that common to have these kind of methods in data model classes. These things should normally be done inside an angular service, updating the data model from there

Comment: @PierreDuc Would you be able to provide a solution that does this inside the `ConversationService` then? Maybe in `addConversation()`?

Comment: @user9847788 I've updated it with a service. Untested code though, but you'll get the idea

Comment: The name of the `addConversation ` parameter `message` is a bit misleading. What's actually being passed in here is just some text from an input. In my answer, I've tried to update `addConversation` to try populate the new message. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211293/discussion-between-user9847788-and-pierreduc).

Comment: @user9847788 It makes sense now :) I've updated my answer

Comment: @PierreDuc Knew we were close! :) Thanks a mill for this, will accept now

Answer (score 0):

Your addConversation function should be this

```
addConversation(userId: string, mechanicId: string, messages: Message[]) {
    const newConversation = new Conversation(conversationId, userId, mechanicId, messages);
  }
```

You use an array in your conversation class, but only give it one message as a parameter.